# unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, dependencies, nativescript

I have seen the similar questions regarding other dependencies, but was unable to apply them to my case (they usually said to uninstall and reinstall newest version, or to install something that was missing. I have globally installed

> @angular/cli@11.0.2
> nativescript@7.0.11
> npm@7.0.14

I am trying to create a nativeScript app (first time) using "tns create myApp", it results in dependency error

> While resolving: @nativescript/template-hello-world-ng@7.0.8 //or any other template
> Could not resolve dependency:
> peer zone.js@"~0.10.3" from @angular/core@11.0.3
> node_modules/@angular/core
> @angular/core@"~11.0.0" from the root project
> peer @angular/core@"11.0.3" from @angular/animations@11.0.3
> node_modules/@angular/animations
> @angular/animations@"~11.0.0" from the root project

everything is in it's latest version, and I do have the core installed, how can this be resolved?
p.s. --force and --legacy-peer-deps changes nothing

Thank you in advance