# Creating new code sharing project in Nativescript gives dependency error on tslint and tslint-rules

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-codesharing, nativescript-schematics

I'm working on a Nativescript project that needs to be converted into native Android code. I have little Nativescript experience so I'm doing a tutorial on "code sharing".

https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project

I've gone through the setup and have all dependencies installed. I can confirm this with `tns doctor`:

```
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 12.4.0 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 7.2.1 version and is up to date.
```

Then I've run the 2 mentioned commands:

```
$ npm i -g @nativescript/schematics

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: typescript@4.2.3
npm WARN node_modules/@nativescript/schematics/node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   peer typescript@">=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >=3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev || >= 3.2.0-dev" from tslint@5.20.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@nativescript/schematics/node_modules/tslint
npm WARN     peer tslint@"^5.16.0" from @nativescript/tslint-rules@0.0.5
npm WARN     node_modules/@nativescript/schematics/node_modules/@nativescript/tslint-rules
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typescript@"^3.4.0" from @nativescript/tslint-rules@0.0.5
npm WARN node_modules/@nativescript/schematics/node_modules/@nativescript/tslint-rules
npm WARN   @nativescript/tslint-rules@"~0.0.5" from @nativescript/schematics@11.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@nativescript/schematics

changed 88 packages in 11s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

And then the second one, but the issue seems to be already in the first command:

```
$ ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics hello-world --shared

⠏ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: hello-world@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: tslint@6.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!   dev tslint@"~6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslint@"^5.16.0" from @nativescript/tslint-rules@0.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@nativescript/tslint-rules
npm ERR!   dev @nativescript/tslint-rules@"~0.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/jclermonts/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jclermonts/.npm/_logs/2021-03-27T16_45_09_004Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167148/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree) seems to be the same. I've also tried `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`
- [Downgrading node as suggested in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages) I could try as a last resort but the question does not answer which specific version I should downgrade to then.

Comment: Hi @Jim, did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi @Jim, Any luck on finding solution, I am too getting same